# Java bubble sort print each sorted line

Tags: java, sorting

I have my bubble sorting algorithm which works correctly but I want to set it up so it prints each line in the process of the final output. I have tried some `if` statements and `for` loops to print out each line of sorting but I can't seem to get exactly what I am trying to do. Here is my code

```
// If bubble sorting is selected here is the code
     if(sortRunner == 1) {               
       int swap; 
       for(int i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
           for(int j = 0; j < list.length - i -1; j++){             
                if(list[j] > list[j+1]){
                    swap = list[j];
                    list[j] = list[j+1];
                    list[j+1] = swap;

                }
            }
         }
         System.out.print("\nThe bubble sort from the numbers are: ");
         for (int k = 0; k < list.length; k++){
            System.out.print(list[k] + " ");
         }
         System.out.println();
     } // End bubble sorting here
```

Comment: What are you actually want to do ? I mean what lines you mean by "print each line" ?

Comment: So you want it to print the current state after each pass?  After each swap?  Or just the final product?

Comment: I want it to print each pass so the user can see the process it is using to sort the values... then getting to the final print statements at the bottom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put `Arrays.toString(list)` to the position you want

This prints line after each step

```
   for(int i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
       for(int j = 0; j < list.length - i -1; j++){             
            if(list[j] > list[j+1]){
                swap = list[j];
                list[j] = list[j+1];
                list[j+1] = swap;

            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
        }
     }
```

This will print actual list after one iteration

```
   for(int i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
       for(int j = 0; j < list.length - i -1; j++){             
            if(list[j] > list[j+1]){
                swap = list[j];
                list[j] = list[j+1];
                list[j+1] = swap;

            }                
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
     }
```

Comment: Don't you need to stick that in an actual print statement? e.g. `System.out.printf("Pass %d.%d: %s\n", i, j, Arrays.toString(list))`.

Comment: Going off of your first solution after each step, I added `Arrays.toString(list)` but I get the error `cannot find symbol` point to `Array`. Does it matter if the array is `int[] list` array?

Comment: you have to add `import java.util.Arrays;` IDE like netbeans are doing this automatically for you, you should use that.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(sortRunner == 1) {               
           int swap; 
           for(int i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
               for(int j = 0; j < list.length - i -1; j++){             
                    if(list[j] > list[j+1]){
                        swap = list[j];
                        list[j] = list[j+1];
                        list[j+1] = swap;
                    }
                    System.out.print(list[j]);
                }
System.out.println();
             }
             System.out.print("\nThe bubble sort from the numbers are: ");
             for (int k = 0; k < list.length; k++){
                System.out.print(list[k] + " ");
             }
             System.out.println();
         } // End bubble sorting here
```

Comment: This `System.out.print(list[j]);` does not work (it prints address in memory)

Comment: list[j] is what is being used to compare values, so it doesn't make sense what you say.

Comment: Because thats how Sun design it and Oracle keeping it.

Comment: @Praktik : Just run this code         `int[] x = new int[10];
        System.out.println(x);`

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate function to print lines:

```
public void printLines (int [] array) {
  System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
}
```

Then call it after the swapping:

```
if(list[j] > list[j+1]){
  swap = list[j];
  list[j] = list[j+1];
  list[j+1] = swap;
  printLines (list);
}
```